# How can I prove that $ S^n \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R} \overset{?}\implies S \notin \mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-numbers

the question came up that if I have a complex number, and take the n-th root of it, whether there is a real solution or not. In more mathematical words it is: $S^n \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R} \overset{?}\implies S \notin \mathbb{R}$ and $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^*$

In order to prove it, I thought that I would start by the contraposition:
 $S^n \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R} \overset{?}\implies S \notin \mathbb{R}$
 $\equiv S \in\mathbb{R} \overset{?}\implies S^n \notin \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$
which is (what symbol should I use here, and is this step right?):
$ S \in\mathbb{R} \overset{?}\implies S^n \in \mathbb{R}$
That seems pretty obvious to me. (If the last step was right,) is it enough as a prove?

Thank you!

Comment: This is correct. It's certainly true that $S \in \Bbb R$ implies that $S^n \in \Bbb R$, as $\Bbb R$ is closed under multiplication.

Comment: Note that what is *not* true is "$S^n\in\mathbb{R}\implies S\in\mathbb{R}$."